# getLoaderManager in ListActivity

Tags: android, listactivity, android-loadermanager

I wish to implement a Loader for in a ListActivity but the activity do not recognize getLoaderManager.

```
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    dbHelper =  new DBHelper(this,DBNAME,FindPackageName(), TABLE_NAME);

    sql = dbHelper.getReadableDataBase();
    //Log.d("Gaurav","Database Open");
    String[] from = new String[]{"word","_id","MyList"};
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.listrow };

    simpleCursorLoader = new SimpleCursorLoader(this, TABLE_NAME, from, null, null, null, null, null, null, sql);



    //query result will be whole database
    //cursor = sql.query(TABLE_NAME, from, null, null, null, null, null);
    //startManagingCursor(cursor); //this method is deprecated
    //Log.d(TAG,"Cursor Set");



    completerOrMyListAdapter = new CompleteOrMyListAdapter(this,
            R.layout.completeormylist_adapter, cursor, from, to, dbHelper); 
    setListAdapter(completerOrMyListAdapter);  

    // Prepare the loader.  Either re-connect with an existing one,
    // or start a new one.
    LoaderManager lm = getLoaderManager();
    //if (lm.getLoader(0) != null) {
    //    lm.initLoader(0, null, this);
    //}
    //getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If your app will only run on API Level 11 or higher, set your build target appropriately, and the method will be available.

However, if you are using the Android Compatibility Library to have support for loaders before API Level 11, you cannot use `ListActivity`. You have to inherit from `FragmentActivity`. Either use a `ListFragment`, or just a plain `ListView` that you manage yourself.

Comment: I tried the answer in my code and it works the way suggested in the answer.

Comment: [The Android Developer website](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html#Using) offers more info on how to use the Support Package (formerly the Compatibility Library) and a few ways in which its libraries differ from the newer libraries they approximate.  You can also check out the links there to the API documentation for the Support Package.

Answer (score 11):

i think you probably use below instead

```
getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
```

if you use the support v4 package

Comment: ... and instead of inheriting from Activity, inherit from FragmentActivity instead.