# Use of setListAdapter

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

In my application 4 fragments are attached to one activity class. In my activity class i have set the root content view using  this

```
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_pager);
```

my four fragments are in seperate java files.

In one of my fragment i am displaying a list of contact for this i used

```
mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null,
                new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME},
                new int[] { android.R.id.text1}, 0);


setListAdapter(mAdapter);
setListShown(true);
```

I want to know that what is the use of setListAdapter in my case and where it put list of content given by SimpleCursorAdapter class? and how can i set the title of my fragment.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:drawable/gallery_thumb">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"/>

    <!-- The frame layout is here since we will be showing either
    the empty view or the list view.  -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
        <!-- Here is the list. Since we are using a ListActivity, we
             have to call it "@android:id/list" so ListActivity will
             find it -->
        <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

        <!-- Here is the view to show if the list is emtpy -->
        <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="No items."/>

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>



 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  

         mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null,
                 new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME},
                 new int[] { android.R.id.text1}, 0);
         //setListAdapter(mAdapter);
        // setListShown(true);
        // getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }    

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pager_list, container, false);
        View tv = v.findViewById(R.id.text);
        ((TextView)tv).setText("Contacts");

        return v;
    }
```

My Cursor display data when i use this method and removes two methods onCreate and onCreateView

```
@Override 
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

       mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null,
                new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME},
                new int[] { android.R.id.text1}, 0);
       setListAdapter(mAdapter); 
       setListShown(true);
       getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

    }
```

but when i use those three methods together then my application stops unexpectedly. What can be the error when i use these three method together?

```
package com.keepintouch.android;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;

import android.provider.ContactsContract;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;

import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.util.Log;

import android.view.View;


import android.widget.ListView;


import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListFragment;


public class ContactsFragment extends SherlockListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

     // This is the Adapter being used to display the list's data.
    SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;

    // If non-null, this is the current filter the user has provided.
    String mCurFilter;  
    View lv;

    // These are the Contacts rows that we will retrieve.
    static final String[] CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION = new String[] {
        ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  

    }    




    public static Fragment newInstance(Context context){
        ContactsFragment contactFragment = new ContactsFragment();
        return contactFragment;
    }


    @Override 
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

       mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null,
                new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME},
                new int[] { android.R.id.text1}, 0);

       setListAdapter(mAdapter); 
       setListShown(true);
       getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

    }



    @Override 
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // Insert desired behavior here.
        Log.i("FragmentComplexList", "Item clicked: " + id);
    }



    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
         // This is called when a new Loader needs to be created.  This
        // sample only has one Loader, so we don't care about the ID.
        // First, pick the base URI to use depending on whether we are
        // currently filtering.
        Uri baseUri;
        if (mCurFilter != null) {
            baseUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
                      Uri.encode(mCurFilter));
        } else {
            baseUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        }

        // Now create and return a CursorLoader that will take care of
        // creating a Cursor for the data being displayed.
        String select = "((" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " NOTNULL) AND ("
                + ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1) AND ("
                + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " != '' ))";
        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), baseUri,
                CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION, select, null,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
    }

    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        // Swap the new cursor in.  (The framework will take care of closing the
        // old cursor once we return.)
        mAdapter.swapCursor(data);

        // The list should now be shown.
        if (isResumed()) {
            setListShown(true);
        } else {
            setListShownNoAnimation(true);
        }
    }

    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        // This is called when the last Cursor provided to onLoadFinished()
        // above is about to be closed.  We need to make sure we are no
        // longer using it.
        mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Listfragement setListAdapter  set the Adapter in your default list comes with Listfragement..

if using action bar (android:targetSdkVersion="15")

```
ActionBar ab =  this.getActionBar();
ab.setTitle("       ");
```

if not then

```
  getActivity().setTitle("     "); // after onAttach called
```

Comment: "set the Adapter in your default list" Which is my default list? i have not used any xml except android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 in my fragment class. How to set the default list?

Comment: and i dont want to change my actionbar title.

Comment: as in query "how can i set the title of my fragment?" where is this title, in your XML?

Comment: how to set the title and list in the above xml?

Comment: please confirm are you want to add one more title below the application title which comes by default on each screen?

Comment: title mens top heading of my fragment's screen. There is a text view above ListView in my xml layout given above.

Comment: in OncreateView (in ListFragment) where you inflating this layout xml get TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text); tv.setText("title");

Comment: no, basically i have created a view pager and i want only a sinle title below my action bar whenever i swipe on the screen. and this title will be different for every screen.

Comment: this works but how to set the my cursor adapter which retruns the list adapter to the listview of the above xml.

Comment: I have just posted my two methods of my fragment class. This sets the textview but how to list the contacts from my cursoradapter to listview of my xml file.

Comment: there is no error. It only shows "Contacts" at top and "No items" below it.

Comment: I have also used this.     ListAdapter la = (ListAdapter)mAdapter;
        View lv = v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        ((ListView)lv).setAdapter(la);

Comment: is cursor is null? in adpter  see this  http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List2.html   &  http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/

Comment: but your reference is for a ListActivity  class and in my case i am writing code in Fragment class.

Comment: I have posted some more things. Please see them.

Comment: your third argument SimpleCursorAdapter( is null which  Cursor ....http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#SimpleCursorAdapter(android.content.Context, int, android.database.Cursor, java.lang.String[], int[], int)

Comment: What could be the problem in my code because my adapter is working fine. I can set the title using onCreateView only one thing i have to do that is to link my adapter to the view in onCreateView.

Comment: sorry ? not get ? and you confirmed your third argument SimpleCursorAdapter( which is null?

Comment: Because i am loading data in the adapter by using loader.

Comment: ok then simple the problem will be in onCreateLoader function.. Please provide that code....

Comment: In logcat i saw an error, "This can not be used with custom content view". and 1 more thing my fragment works fine without onCreateView. But it show only contact list without any title.

Comment: i want to show a title "Contacts" below ActionBar and contact list below Contact title.

Comment: I have posted above please see it.

Comment: can you also provide the log cat having "This can not be used with custom content view".

Comment: give me some minutes because i have changed my fragment class.

Comment: 06-08 16:21:04.255: E/AndroidRuntime(2663): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't be used with a custom content view

Comment: I know you are using same just FYI http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622913/getloadermanager-in-listactivity